# C Formula help circular positiong

Tags: c, geometry, trigonometry

I am trying to calculate the angle at which the a ball spinning in a circle lands on. 
I have this to make it move around a circle:

```
    BallPositionX = (cos( degreesToRadiansMultiplier * BallPositionAngle ) * 215) + centerPointX;
    BallPositionY = centerPointY - (sin( degreesToRadiansMultiplier * BallPositionAngle ) * 215);
```

The 'BallPositionAngle' is calculated by:

```
    BallPositionAngle += (BallSpeed * multiplier);
```

Where the 'BallSpeed' is a random number between 1 and 100 and the 'multiplier' is the frame number in the animation. This is repeated every frame until frame number 78 when the ball stops.

I wrote this formula to actually work out its final angle:

```
Winning = ((2*acos(((BallPositionX-centerPointX)/215)))/degreesToRadiansMultiplier);
```

The formula keeps giving me an almost random angle every time which is nowhere near the balls actual position.

Can anyone think of an easier way to do this? Or correct anything I have done?
I need an angle in degrees for the rest of my code to function.

I am using C and have no idea what compiler my lecturer is making me use.

Comment: Have you printed out all the values, to find out where the problem is?  Why are you multiplying the angles by 215?  Why isn't 215 a named constant?  What is the type of `multiplier`?  Can't you make the calculations more symmetric by putting `centerPointX + (cos(…))` above `centerPointY - (sin(…))`?  It makes it easier to read the code when you keep it symmetric.

Comment: 215 is the radius of the balls trajectory and multiplier is just an     int that's incremented each time the frame is finished.

Comment: I think you should have a variable called 'radius' or thereabouts in place of the 215.  However, that's relatively a minor issue.  I think you should provide more nearly compilable code, along with starting values for all the parameters of the calculation, plus an explanation of what you think the output should be (and maybe some information about what you're getting as the output. What are the units of the `BallSpeed`?  Degrees per frame? Have you considered using `atan2()` instead of `acos()`?

Comment: I'm still having problems understanding the first sentence. Do you mean something like: _There is a ball rotating around a centre point at a fixed radius and speed of rotation and I need calculate its position at fixed intervals of time?_  I suspect that's not what you're after, but I'm not sure what you _are_ after.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure your `BallPositionAngle` formula needs to drop the `+`:

```
BallPositionAngle = (BallSpeed * multiplier);
```

Comment: Dropping the plus did nothing :(

Comment: Dropping the `+` must have changed the calculation.  It may not have made the results measurably better, but it must have altered them.